# if $g\circ f$ is surjective then $g$ is surjective where$f: A\to B$ and $g: B\to C$

Tags: functions

Can someone please check if my proof for this question is correct?

[image]

Comment: You've shown that if $g\circ f$ is surjective, it is possible that $f$ is not surjective. That is not a counter-example.

Comment: Why does "that also means that $A(0)\to B(1)?$"

Comment: Your notation is somewhat odd - we don't really write $B(1)\to C(3)$ in this context. We write $g(1)=3.$

Answer (score 1):

Let $c\in C$. We want to find some $ b \in B $ such that $ g (b) = c $ (this shows that $g$ is surjective).

But since $ g \circ f $ is surjective, we can guarantee that there exists $ a \in A $ such that $(g\circ f)(a)=c$. (Since 
$$g(f(a))=(g\circ f)(a)=c$$
we can choose $f(a)$ as the desired $b$). Finally, define $b:=f(a)$.